# How to include the project name when passing the path to getResourceAsStream()?

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources

How can I specify the project in the path to access the right .properties file with getResourceAsStream()? The problem is that folder and file name are equal in subproject A and B (so simply specifying folder/file as path won't do it.
Is there a solution similar to
*.getResourceAsStream("/Subproject_B/someFolder/someResourceBundle.properties")*? Do I need to implement my own classloader and set only the projects/folder I want to be searched for on its classpath? Would that lead to an unique address when loading the file like *.getResourceAsStream("/someFolder/someResourceBundle.properties")*?

Our Maven project looks like that:

```
SubProject_A
          |-src
            |-main
              |-resources
                |-someFolder                     //folder name is the same as in Subproject_B
                  |-someResourceBundle.properties

SubProject_B
      |-src
        |-main
          |-resources
            |-someFolder                   //folder name is the same as in Subproject_A
              |-someResourceBundle.properties
```

Comment: The `getResource` family of methods work from the classpath, not the file system. So don't think of folders and files, think of packages and resources. The classpath should have `src/main/resources` in the classpath, so the argument to a `getResource...()` call to access `someResourceBundle.properties` would be `/someFolder/someResourceBundle.properties`.

Comment: This shows a problem, cause if you name them the same it means the belong together into the same module or your separation is wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

One could consider the two resources as belonging to two jars.
The `Class.getResource` is specific to the class:

```
ClassInJarA.class.getResourceAsStream("/...")
```

The system `ClassLoader` uses the full class path as specified, using a path without a leading slash. Stopping at the first match.

(Also mind that using `.getClass().getResource` is dangerous because of inheritance.)

I would use the Class.getResourceAsStream being more specific.

Comment: "more specific" than what, and in what way?

Comment: @LewBloch not on the entire class path, but the jar of the class. A ClassLoader would in general use a class path and stop with the first match.

Comment: `Class#getResource...` "delegates to this object's class loader", so the methods are the same, yes?

Comment: @LewBloch: right. As in general there are several class loaders, and the search order then becomes a bit fuzzy (for me), I would try it out. This class's class loader should start with its jar.

Answer (score 0):

Put each project's resources in a package that distinguishes the resources as you want. For example, `/com/example/project_a/somePackage/someResourceBundle.properties` and `/com/example/project_b/somePackage/someResourceBundle.properties`. No need for a custom classloader if you do things the Java way and segregate through the use of packages.

It's usually a bad idea to use a complex kludge to work around a deliberate straying from the normal way to do things.